# Dart - How to take multiple output values and multiply with a single value?

Tags: dictionary, dart

This is my first project of my own on my self-taught, Dart/Flutter/coding road.

I’m trying to make an Animal Age Calculator. Basically, the user will select an animal from a group of animals and give the age of the animal and the code will output the relative age against other animals.

I’ve got a number of Maps (I think) with key:value pairs. Each Map has a k:v pair (animal and its corresponding age ratio). For example, if the user selects ‘dog’ the code will return the dogMap and the ratio values for bear, cat, chicken, elephant, human and rabbit.

I can get the ratio values but am stuck trying to use those values to calculate the relative age.

Here is the map -

```
var dogAgeRatio = {'dogTobear': 0.55, 'dogTocat': 0.88, 'dogTochicken': 1.47, 'dogToelephant': 0.31, 'dogTohuman': 0.28, 'dogTorabbit': 2.44};
```

and here is what I have so far to get the values -

```
if(animalName == "dog") {
    print("these are the relatve animal ages: ${dogAgeRatio.values}");
```

Would appreciate a pointer as to how I should go about using those values and apply a calculation to return the relative age of all the other animals?

Thanks in advance.

Cal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do this but a simple way is something like this where we have a `Map<String, Map<String, num>>` to represent our comparisons:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final animalMap = {
    'dog': {
      'bear': 0.55,
      'cat': 0.88,
      'chicken': 1.47,
      'elephant': 0.31,
      'human': 0.28,
      'rabbit': 2.44
    },
    'alien': {
      'human': 100
    }
  };

  print('Please enter one of the following animals:');
  print('==========================================');
  animalMap.keys.forEach(print);
  print('==========================================');

  final animalInput = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (animalInput != null && animalMap.containsKey(animalInput)) {
    print('Enter age of animal:');
    final age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

    print('Age compared to different animals:');
    print('==========================================');
    animalMap[animalInput]!.entries.forEach((element) =>
        print('${element.key} => ${element.value * age} years old.'));
    print('==========================================');
  } else {
    print('Wrong animal!');
  }
}
```

So first key is the starting animal and the sub-map is how we get from the starting animal age to the sub-animal.

I have made my solution a little interactive just for fun. :)

Comment: thx @julemand101, this is quite a comprehensive answer. Give me a couple of weeks and I might understand what is happening. I will return to it for sure and use it to compare and improve on my own attemp. Thanks

Comment: @CStep Just say if there are parts of the solution you want me to explain in more details. And yes, it can be difficult for a beginner to read this code since I have used some shortcuts to make the code shorter which are properly not obvious how it works. I can also rewrite the solution to split up each step in more details.

Comment: thx, you have been a great help. I was alble to take one part of your solution and adapt (through trial and erro) into my own. It feels like a small win for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understaind you correctly, but you could use something like:

```
dogAgeRatio.values.forEach((element) { print(element * dogage);});
```

Which basically iterates over every item of your map and prints the value multiplied with the dogs age.

Comment: @ Danzon2504 - after asking my question I was able to qualify my google search further and came back with something similar -  `var selectedList = dogAgeRatio.values.toList();` - followed by -
`for (double item in selectedList) {
    print(item * howOld);
}' - thanks for your response. Once I've finished the project I'll try and re-work it to include your suggestion. Thanks again.